# FileSystemWatcher issues

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I am trying to use the FileSystemWatcher - and am having some luck..

The goal is to MOVE the file that gets created, from the monitored folder, to a new folder.

But... have hit 2 snags. Firstly, if I move 3 files into a folder at once (Select 3 files, ctrl+x, and then ctrl+c into my Monitor Folder), the monitor only triggers for the first file. The other 2 don't get processed.

```
            FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(FolderToMonitor);
        fsw.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(fsw_Created);

        bool monitor = true;

        while (monitor)
        {
            fsw.WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes.All, 2000);
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                monitor = false;
            }
        }

        Show("User has quit the process...", ConsoleColor.Yellow);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Is there a way to make it see all 3?

Secondly, if I move a file into the monitor folder, from a different drive, it takes a few seconds to copy the file into the folder. However, the monitor triggers as soon as the file starts copying in.. so therefore, is read only, and not ready to be moved.

Is there a way I can wait for the file to complete it's copy into the monitor folder, before I process it?

Comment: I made an error... It's not readonly... the error is that the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. Is there a way, in code, to check that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx):

> The Windows operating system notifies
>   your component of file changes in a
>   buffer created by the
>   FileSystemWatcher. If there are many
>   changes in a short time, the buffer
>   can overflow. This causes the
>   component to lose track of changes in
>   the directory, and it will only
>   provide blanket notification.
>   Increasing the size of the buffer with
>   the InternalBufferSize property is
>   expensive, as it comes from non-paged
>   memory that cannot be swapped out to
>   disk, so keep the buffer as small yet
>   large enough to not miss any file
>   change events. To avoid a buffer
>   overflow, use the NotifyFilter and
>   IncludeSubdirectories properties so
>   you can filter out unwanted change
>   notifications.

Perhaps that explains your issue?
Also note that cutting and pasting files from one directory to another is basically a mere renaming operation, therefore you should use the `Renamed` event to detect them.

As for your other problem: try using the `Changed` event together with `Created`, as I believe both will be raised exactly once for a file (note that moving a file from another drive in not a simple renaming operation: it's copy and delete), so the `Changed` event should indicate when the file copy operation has been completed (i.e. it won't fire until the file is complete).

Comment: Note that if there are other processes writing a file to the target directory (other than cut/paste) multiple `Changed` events might be fired, and the file might still be in use after the first one.

Comment: Thanks @ShdNx - I only copied 3 files at once... Would that be a case for an overflow, or are they talking hundreds of files before the buffer fills? It's very unspecific to me. I'll look into the Changed Event. I was going to cheat, and have a While loop that tries to open the file in Write mode... And then if there's an exception, assume ReadOnly... wait a while, and try again, until I can open it (File.Open) successfully in Write mode, and then that means the file is OK. Bad in many ways?

Comment: @cdotlister: to be honest I'm not sure. I suggest try increasing the buffer size (say, multiply it with 2) and then check if you get more notifications. Also you should try subscribing to all exposed events (except Disposed), just to see if there's an internal IO operation you're missing. That while loop sounds like an evil idea, but sometimes it's the only viable option. If nothing else works, you shouldn't be afraid to use evil solution, but keep in mind (and add a comment to the code) that it's bad and should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: You can find out for sure if you are getting the InternalBufferOverflowException by subscribing to the OnError event and checking the exception type in the event args.