# .Net Windows Service and FileSystemWatcher issue

Tags: .net, windows, service, filesystemwatcher

I have searched through lots of fourm and did not find any solution to the below problem, I am hopeful that some one would be able to help me in this forum.

I have .net windows service with two FSWs which monitors folders on network.

structure of folders
\NetworkDrive\NewFolder\InputDirectory
\NetworkDrive\NewFolder\WorkingDirectory

When I copy multiple file to \NetworkDrive\NewFolder\InputDirectory directory, lets say file1, file2, file3 and file4 then only file1, file2 and file3 are processed and it leaves one file

Below is code of service class and filesystemwatcher class

Service Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace Service1
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
    public FaxInbound()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ServiceName = "Service1";
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        onServiceStartProcess();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        try
        {
        workingSysTimer.Enabled = false;
        inboundSysTimer.Enabled = false;
        workingSysTimer.Stop();
        inboundSysTimer.Stop();
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
        throw new ProblemException(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
        }
    }

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    private void inboundSysTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        WatchFileSystem.Run(inboundFSW, inputDirectory, directoryWatchfilter);
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
        throw new ProblemException(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
        }
        finally
        {
        inboundSysTimer.Enabled = true;
        inboundSysTimer.Start();
        }
    }

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    private void workingSysTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        WatchFileSystem.Run(workingFSW, workingDirectory, directoryWatchfilter);
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
        throw new ProblemException(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
        }
        finally
        {
        workingSysTimer.Enabled = true;
        workingSysTimer.Start();
        }
    }

    internal void onServiceStartProcess()
    {
        try
        {
        setConfig();
        inboundSysTimer.Enabled = true;
        workingSysTimer.Enabled = true;
        inboundSysTimer.Start();
        workingSysTimer.Start();
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
        throw new ProblemException(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

FileSystemwatcher Class

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace Service1
{
    [Serializable()]
    internal class WatchFileSystem
    {
    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
    internal static void Run(System.IO.FileSystemWatcher watcher, string directoryPath = "", string fileFilter = "*.*")
    {
        try
        {
        string args = directoryPath;

        if (args.Length < 3)
        {
            return;
        }

        watcher.Path = args;

        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.FileName;

        watcher.Filter = fileFilter;
        watcher.InternalBufferSize = 64;

        if (watcher.Path == inputDirectory)
        {
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnInputDirectoryChanged);
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnInputDirectoryChanged);
            watcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(OnInputDirectoryError);
        }

        if (watcher.Path == workingDirectory)
        {
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnWorkingDirectoryChanged);
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnWorkingDirectoryChanged);
            watcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(OnWorkingDirectoryError);
        }

        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
        throw new ProblemException(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
        }
    }


    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    internal static void OnInputDirectoryChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        System.IO.FileStream file = null;
        try
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(e.FullPath) == true)
            {
            file = File.Open(e.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Yield();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); // hack for timing issues
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (file != null)
            file.Dispose();
        }

        if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created)
        {
            System.IO.FileInfo infoFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(e.FullPath);
            if (infoFile.Exists == true)
            {
            infoFile = null;
            try
            {
                if (file != null)
                {
                file.Close();
                file.Dispose();
                }

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(e.FullPath) == true)
                {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(workingDirectory, e.Name)) == false)
                {
                    System.IO.File.Move(e.FullPath, System.IO.Path.Combine(workingDirectory, e.Name));
                }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Yield();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); // hack for timing issues   
                return;
            }
            }
        }
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
        throw new ProblemException(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
        }
    }

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    private static void OnInputDirectoryError(object source, ErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        System.IO.FileSystemWatcher inboundFSW = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher();
        inboundFSW.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        inboundFSW.IncludeSubdirectories = false;

        while (!inboundFSW.EnableRaisingEvents)
        {
        try
        {
            WatchFileSystem.Run(inboundFSW, inputDirectory, directoryWatchfilter);
        }
        catch
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
        }
    }


    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    internal static void OnWorkingDirectoryChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        System.IO.FileStream file = null;
        try
        {   
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(e.FullPath) == true)
            {
            file = File.Open(e.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Yield();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); // hack for timing issues   
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (file != null)
            file.Dispose();
        }

        if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created)
        {
            System.IO.FileInfo infoFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(e.FullPath);
            if (infoFile.Exists == true)
            {
            infoFile = null;
                try
                {
                if (file != null)
                {
                    file.Close();
                    file.Dispose();
                }

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(e.FullPath) == true)
                {
                    generateFiles(System.IO.Path.Combine(workingDirectory, e.Name));
                }
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                System.Threading.Thread.Yield();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); // hack for timing issues  
                return;
                }
            }
        }
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
        throw new ProblemException(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
        }
    }

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    private static void OnWorkingDirectoryError(object source, ErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        System.IO.FileSystemWatcher workingFSW = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher();
        workingFSW.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        workingFSW.IncludeSubdirectories = false;

        while (!workingFSW.EnableRaisingEvents)
        {
        try
        {
            WatchFileSystem.Run(workingFSW, workingDirectory, directoryWatchfilter);
        }
        catch
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you set the `InternalBufferSize` to 64 bytes? The default is 8192 bytes (8 KB). This could be the problem.

Comment: this is the issue with filewatcher. write down your own code to check for files. One more issue, you will try to pick the files if file is not copied fully on the disk because filewatcher gas created event, not the completed event.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have not found an answer, please refer to: 
[FileSystemWatcher issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000856/filesystemwatcher-issues)

Have you considered using a polling system instead? You can use create a new thread, check for new files and copy/move them and then use `Thread.Sleep()` to put the thread to sleep for a certain time interval of your choice. And loop through this process.