# FileSystemWatcher threading and timing issue

Tags: c#, multithreading

We have an application that "prints" employee W2's to PDF.  Unfortunately, the app doesn't password protect the PDF.

I've written a service that uses FileSystemWatcher to look for the PDF as its created.  It then grabs the PDF and uses ASPose.PDF to add password and encryption to the PDF.

My first issue is timing.  I've had to embed a Thread.Sleep(2000) in my code after FileSystemWatcher calls my event handler notifying me of a newly created file.  If I don't do that, I run into an issue where ASPose.PDF is unable to get the access it needs to the file because it is in use -- apparently not yet released by the creating application.  It's kind of a smelly solution and I'd love some input if there is a better way of handling that.

However, my bigger issue is that I'd like to implement async processing with Tasks to get better performance when thousands of files are being generated.  I'm pretty much a newb when it comes to working with Tasks and threading.

This is what I'm planning to do with Tasks ... Is this the right approach?

```
public class W2PDFEncryptionService : ServiceBase
{
    private FileSystemWatcher _watcher = null;
    private Aspose.Pdf.License _license = null;
    private string _connectionString = "";
    private string _targetDir = "";
    private string _masterPassword = "";
    private const int SLEEPTIME = 2000;
    private const string PASSFORMAT = "[{0}!{1}]";

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);

        ReadAppSettings();

        //Log current run state
        _builder.Clear();
        _builder.AppendLine("Sarting Service");
        _builder.AppendLine("   Monitor Directory: " + _targetDir);
        _builder.AppendLine("   SQL Connection: " + _connectionString);
        this.EventLog.WriteEntry(_builder.ToString());

        ConfigureFileWatcher();
    }

    private void ConfigureFileWatcher()
    {
        // _watcher is a private property of the service
        _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(_targetDir); 
        _watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        _watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.CreationTime;

        _watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        _watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRename);

        _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void OnRename(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task task = ProcessFile(e.FullPath, "PDF Renamed - " + e.OldName + " to " + e.Name + " in folder " + Path.GetDirectoryName(e.FullPath));
    }

    private void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Task task = ProcessFile(e.FullPath, "PDF Created - " + e.Name + " in folder " + Path.GetDirectoryName(e.FullPath));
    }

    private async Task ProcessFile(string filename, string logtext)
    {
        //Pause for two seconds to ensure file is not in use
        //Thread.Sleep(SLEEPTIME);
        Task.Delay(SLEEPTIME);

        EncryptFile(filename, _userPassword); //this is where ASPose.PDF is used
    }
```

It appears that this would allow the service to kick of a new processing/encryption task for each PDF that gets created or renamed.

(Granted, each thread will have to create its own instance of ASPose.PDF in order to process its file to avoid locking isuses)

Am I missing anything here?

P.S.  As I've thought about this a bit more, it seems like I have no way to account for the service being Paused or Stopped with outstanding threads.

Comment: You can keep trying to open the file with exponential back off if you don't have permission; the reason you can't open it right away is that the other program is busy writing the file (the 'created' event is fired as soon as the file is first opened, not when it's finally closed). It's still a workaround, but it's more correct than  waiting a fixed amount of time.

Comment: You might take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000856/filesystemwatcher-issues. In particular the bit about looking for Changed files rather than Created files. Also, rather than starting a new task for each file, have your events just put the file name on a queue (a `BlockingCollection`). Have one or more long-running tasks that read items from that queue and process them. That way, you limit the number of outstanding tasks, and you can more easily shut them down.

Comment: When you get an FSW notification, you can pretty much count on *not* being able to open the file.  Since some program just changed the file, it didn't close it yet.  Using threads to read "thousands of files" is a very bad idea, high odds that throughput is significantly lower.  Just from forcing the disk drive reader head to jump back and forth constantly.

Comment: Hans, how then would you handle a scenario like mine where we need those files encrypted whenever they get created?  Would you do something like what Jim mentioned using a BlockingCollection and a single long-running task?

Comment: I'd use the built-in operating system feature that provides encryption.  No code necessary, completely opaque to the app that writes the file, somebody else to blame when sensitive data gets revealed anyway.  Bitlocker on Windows.

Comment: That would work except that we also need to send these files to our employees via email and we have a requirement that they be encrypted/password protected as an attachment as well.

Comment: Jim, if you'll post your comment as an answer, I'll go ahead and select it.  In the end, this is the route I went and it seems to work fairly well.