# C# filesystemwatcher does not trigger with large amount of files

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I have written a windows service in which I have a FileSystemWatcher on a folder that should trigger when a file is created. But when I copy a large amount of files simultaneously in this folder, it will trigger for some files only (about 30 on 150). A week ago, it was working normally, it would trigger for the 150 files.

If I add the files one by one in the folder, it will trigger for each.

Does anyone have any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6001055/613130

Comment: A good start would be the documentation for `FileSystemWatcher`. It tells you about many caveats of using it to detect file changes. The top would probably be buffer overflow and incorrect filtering. Are you doing work in the event handler? You should really just dispatch the message as fast as possible to a different thread.

Comment: try increase  the [FileSystemWatcher.InternalBufferSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.internalbuffersize.aspx), or\and use [NotifyFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: So, i tried adding one NotifyFilter and it is triggering on more files. And then, increasing the FileSystemWatcher.InternalBufferSize solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: @Stan you might want to sum up the way you solved it and answer your own question.